# My browse window in tkinter goes under the toplevel tkinter window where topmost enabled

Tags: python, tkinter

I will try to simplify my question here. My problem is like, on my first window of tkinter I have a button that opens another tkinter window. You can say it a second window to keep it on top I use `win2.attributes('-topmost', True)`. Then I have a browse button to import file from the computer but when I click it goes under the window 2.

Following is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.title("Base Window")
root.geometry("300x300")


def browse():
    file_to_open = askopenfilename()

def new_window():
    win2 = Toplevel(root)
    win2.title("Window 2")
    win2.geometry("300x300")
    win2.attributes('-topmost', True)
    Button2 = Button(win2, text="Browse", command=browse).pack()


button1 = Button(root, text="New window", command=new_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

My browse window is going under the window 2. Can you please suggest me the best way to keep it on top. I am sharing the screenshot of the problem as well

**Starting code**

[image: Starting my program]

**Click on new window**

[image: Click on new window]

Click **browse button** and the browse window is hidden

[image: Hidden browse window]

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `parent` option of `askopenfilename()` to the toplevel window `win2`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.title("Base Window")
root.geometry("300x300")

def browse(parent):
    file_to_open = askopenfilename(parent=parent)

def new_window():
    win2 = Toplevel(root)
    win2.title("Window 2")
    win2.geometry("300x300")
    win2.attributes('-topmost', True)
    # pass 'win2' to browse()
    Button2 = Button(win2, text="Browse", command=lambda:browse(win2)).pack()


button1 = Button(root, text="New window", command=new_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```